# Another DIV CSS vertical alignment issue

Tags: css, alignment, center, vertical-alignment

I know there are a million questions about CSS vertical alignment but I believe I have a slightly new flavour of problem.

I have a container layer and a sublayer inside that, the internal layer has fixed size, however my wrapper layer has a variable height, percentage, with a fixed minimum height.
The issue I have is that I'm able to align it vertically middle either for the min-height scenario or the percentage height scenario but not both.

I have a feeling that the solution will most likely be involving jQuery to determine the height of the wrapper layer in pixels and applying the negative margin to the internal layer on the fly, using position:rel; top:50%; but thought I would asking incase anyone has come across this before.

My css has the following properties:

```
#container {
height:82%;
min-height:600px;
width:938px;
}
#container div {
width:400px;
height:400px;
padding:70px;
border-radius:100%;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the  container layer a css property value of `display: table`. I think that would fix your issue.

```
#container {
    display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing new to this question.
Still, here is the answer:

```
#container {
height:82%;
min-height:600px;
width:938px;
position: relative;
}
#container div {
width:400px;
height:400px;
padding:70px;
border-radius:100%;
text-align:center;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%
margin-top: -270px;
margin-left: -270px;
}
```

Another posiibility would be to set the container to display: table and the inner div to display: table-cell and vertical-align: middle.

Comment: This doesn't work correctly, will create a JSFiddle if you like

Comment: also the margins need to be -270 to accommodate the padding

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see the padding. You need to set the margins to -270px.